# Textfileld doesn't support Persian language inside Bottomshet

Tags: flutter

I am writing an app using Flutter in Persian (locale fa) and I think the Bottomshet widget does not support it well. Everything about English is fine but when I type Persian the text is not rtl.
Thanks a lot.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A shot in the dark: you can wrap the code in BottomSheet with `Directionality` widget:

```
showBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) {
    return Directionality(
      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
      child: Container(), // your widget tree
    );
  },
);
```